# Need helping putting images side by side

Tags: html, css

images are populated dynamically based on what services each location offers so there could 1-5 images that need to go side by side.
New to editing CSS.  What would div class would I need to control to get both of .png examples on one row using CSS knowing that there could be as many as 5 images needed to go on that row from the different tag groups from the screenshot

```html
<div class="com_locator_taglist ml_withdescription ml_tag_count_6">
<div class="ml_tag_group_name modalityimagetype">Modality / Image Type</div>
<div class="ml_tag_group modalityimagetype ml_tag_group_1"><span class="ml_tagtext ml_sub mri ml_tag_1">&nbsp;&nbsp;MRI</span></div>
<div class="ml_tag_group modalityimagetype ml_tag_group_3"><img class="ml_tag_image ml_tag_group_3 xray ml_tag_3" src="https://d23g0hayoxy5dh.cloudfront.net/ul/3629/images/xray-icon-blue.png" alt="X-Ray"><span class="ml_tagtext ml_sub xray ml_tag_3">&nbsp;&nbsp;X-Ray</span></div>
<div class="ml_tag_group modalityimagetype ml_tag_group_2"><span class="ml_tagtext ml_sub catscan ml_tag_2">&nbsp;&nbsp;CAT Scan</span></div>
<div class="ml_tag_group modalityimagetype ml_tag_group_4"><img class="ml_tag_image ml_tag_group_4 ultrasound ml_tag_4" src="https://d23g0hayoxy5dh.cloudfront.net/ul/3629/images/ultrasound-blue.png" alt="UltraSound"><span class="ml_tagtext ml_sub ultrasound ml_tag_4">&nbsp;&nbsp;UltraSound</span></div><div class="ml_tag_group modalityimagetype ml_tag_group_10"><span class="ml_tagtext ml_sub mriwcontrast ml_tag_10">&nbsp;&nbsp;MRI W/ Contrast</span></div>
<div class="ml_tag_group modalityimagetype ml_tag_group_11"><span class="ml_tagtext ml_sub mriwwocontrast ml_tag_11">&nbsp;&nbsp;MRI W/ &amp; W/O Contrast</span></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: .sidebyside{display:flex;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `display: flex` on the container div, and then `display: flex 1` to equally space the images apart. I've also added `max-height` and `max-width` to keep the icons within the same sizes

If you're going to being using `display: flex`, you should also consider checking out [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), as it shows a lot of helpful examples, and is a nice little cheatsheet

```css
#imageContainer {
  display: flex;
}

#imageContainer div {
  display: flex;
}

#imageContainer div > img {
  display: flex 1;

  max-height: 75px;
  max-width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer">
  <div>Modality / Image Type</div>

  <div>
    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;MRI</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://d23g0hayoxy5dh.cloudfront.net/ul/3629/images/xray-icon-blue.png" alt="X-Ray">
    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;X-Ray</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;CAT Scan</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://d23g0hayoxy5dh.cloudfront.net/ul/3629/images/ultrasound-blue.png" alt="UltraSound">
    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;UltraSound</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;MRI W/ Contrast</span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;MRI W/ &amp; W/O Contrast</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you do it like that, the responsiveness will be a mess

Answer (score 1):

Put your images in a parent div, and then style that div accordingly:

```
.container { 
   display: flex;
   align-content: center;
}
```

You can also check a flex-box guide for more styling regarding your problem.